Getting right order of `declaredMemberProperties` in a `listOf<Any>`
Edit: The "already answered answer" doesn't get me the values of the data class object. I can only access the field name and the order id, but NOT the value (here "0", "A", "H", "B")
My Android App works with multiple database tables. Here a two extreme simple examples about the structure:
data class Table1(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var dataA: String,
    var dataH: String,
    var dataB: String
)

data class Table2(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var dataG: String,
    var dataC: String,
    var dataD: String
)

They should be exportable (simple conversion from table headers and values to a CSV). The function here translates it perfectly fine, but sort the table cols alphabetical. I need the declaredMemberProperties in the same order as in the data classes.
fun datatableToStrings(tableDatasets: List<Any>) : String {
    // Buffer list
    val bufferList = mutableListOf("")

    for (j in tableDatasets.indices) {
        bufferList.add("")
    }

    // Store the return value
    var resultString = ""

    tableDatasets[0].javaClass.kotlin.declaredMemberProperties.forEach {
        // Header
        bufferList[0] += "${it};"

        // Values
        for (j in tableDatasets.indices) {
            bufferList[j + 1] += it.get(tableDatasets[j]!!).toString() + ";"
        }
    }

    // Merge all together
    for (j in bufferList) {
        resultString += j + "\n"
    }

    return resultString
}


...

// Call from other class/function:
Log.d("AAA", datatableToStrings(listOf(Table1(0, "A", "H", "B"))))

The wished result should look like this:
0;A;H;B;

But it returns to this:
A;B;H;0;

I`m glad if someone can help me.

You can indeed use the "already answered answer" to get the values, given the list of fields. Just replace tableDatasets[0].javaClass.kotlin.declaredMemberProperties with tableDatasets[0].javaClass.declaredFields.
